# USB formatting error

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount, usb-drive

I tried formating my USB using `disks`. The result was:

```
Error formatting volume

Error creating file system: Command-line `mkfs.vfat -I -n "sara" "/dev/sdc"' exited with non-zero exit status 1:
stdout: `mkfs.fat 3.0.26 (2014-03-07)
'
stderr: `mkfs.fat: warning - lowercase labels might not work properly with DOS or Windows
mkfs.vfat: failed whilst writing FAT
' (udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

Then I tried GParted and there are two options (new, information). I click on "new" and it says:

```
A partition table is required before partitions can be added.
To create a new partition table choose the menu item:
Device --> Create Partition Table)
```

Click on device, create partition table (`msdos`) and it gives me a message:

```
Input/output error during read on /dev/sdc
```

Retry does nothing so I press ignore and then my PC automatically removes my USB. I remove it and reconnect and still can't read my USB or see it in Files (Nautilus).

---

The output of `lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b3b1 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 058f:6366 Alcor Micro Corp. Multi Flash Reader
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0930:0220 Toshiba Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 018: ID 0951:1665 Kingston Technology 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting it, then umount it then try to partition it with a 
 `"sudo mkfs.vfat -F32 -I /dev/sdX"`

Comment: how can i unmount usb gparted give me no option just (new, information )

Comment: what's the output of lsusb

Comment: i put output as answer beacuse it's too long

Comment: using  (sudo mkfs.vfat -F32 -I /dev/sdX) give me    **mkfs.fat 3.0.26 (2014-03-07)
mkfs.vfat: failed whilst writing FAT
**

Comment: That's weird, try this "sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb" then unplug and plug in usb and then try formatting